# How to debug keyboard shortcuts not working?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, xev

I'm on XUbuntu 15.10. I noticed that some keyboard shortcuts don't reach my application (Sublime Text).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is not visible by the application, while for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> is recognised correctly.

I tried to debug the problem with `xev`, here's what I'm seeing.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> gives me:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 473258, (88,-10), root:(4850,512),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 473378, (88,-10), root:(4850,512),
    state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 473530, (88,-10), root:(4850,512),
    state 0xc, keycode 31 (keysym 0x69, i), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) "       "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 473602, (88,-10), root:(4850,512),
    state 0xc, keycode 31 (keysym 0x69, i), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 473770, (88,-10), root:(4850,512),
    state 0xc, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 473778, (88,-10), root:(4850,512),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

but <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+P</kbd> gives:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 508401, (90,-17), root:(4852,505),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 508497, (90,-17), root:(4852,505),
    state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967289 0   0   0   32  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 508785, (90,-17), root:(4852,505),
    state 0xc, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0xf9, subw 0x0, time 508793, (90,-17), root:(4852,505),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

No `KeyPress` or `KeyRelease` for <kbd>p</kbd>, instead there's a cryptic `KeymapNotify`.

I've looked at `xfce4-settings-editor` but found no matching key binding there.

Where do I go from here? How can I find what steals this key combination?

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue before. Another application was already using the keyboard shortcut, but it was not showing in Keyboard > Application Shortcuts. Therefore, it could not re-assign.

In Terminal, use your favorite text editor to open the following:

```
gedit ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

I assume you want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. Search for the line with `&lt;Primary&gt;&lt;Alt&gt;p` and delete it. Now try to set your keyboard shortcut for Sublime Text.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no luck with this. I only have Super+P configured to run `xfce4-display-settings`, I was able to see that one in `xfce4-settings-editor` as well.